# How to Embed You Tube video in small size?

Tags: c#

I am designing a webpage on asp.net with C# as programming language. I would like to embed YouTube video on my webpage. The YouTube video URL is coming from database.
The user has right to update his YouTube video for that there is one textbox in which they paste the YouTube video embed code and submit it and the YouTube video embed code got inserted in database.
The video is being displayed on webpage through literal control. But the problem is that when that video displays on webpage taking the YouTube video URL from database it is of very large size as embed code contains width ="853" height="480" parameter also.
I would like to display the video of width="300" and height ="250". How to do this. Please help me.

SAMPLE Embed code

Comment: I gather the URL is stored as string? If so, you can perform a Replace operation on the string before it is bound to the control... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=netcore-3.1 and set it to your desired values

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regex and replace in youtube's iframe width and height. 
Example:

```
            // new width and height
            string newWidth = "width=\"300\"";
            string newHeight = "height=\"250\"";
            string iframeYoutube =
                "<iframe width=\"560\" height=\"315\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/a9WxNvINTmU\" frameborder=\"0\" allow=\"accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture\" allowfullscreen></iframe>";

            var newIframe = Regex.Replace(iframeYoutube, "width=[\\\"|']\\d+[\\\"|']", newWidth);
            newIframe = Regex.Replace(newIframe, "height=[\\\"|']\\d+[\\\"|']", newHeight);
```